# using keepass (or other pw tool) to fill windows credentials?

Tags: keepass, credentials, credentials-manager

Can we use KEEPASS to auto-fill the window credential? or are there any password tool can do ít?
many thanks!
detail for my problem: I work a lot with some resources using window credential as log-in method, so manual-type them is some kind terrible, store them in a window vault not a choice, because the policy make me change them every 15 days , and then I must remove all the vault and re-create them.

---

update :
I've tried "*.mycompany.com" and "10.*" (my sites are on servers with IP like 10.16.34.169) but it doesn't work! Are there any help to troubleshot this problem?

---

this is not an answer but a solution for someone has this problem like me!
Using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and a piece of code below, you can forgot the Credential manager! just edit the *.ahk file when you change password.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ahk_class #32770
    ^!a:: Send youdomain.com\yourid{Tab}YourPa$$w0rd{Enter}
return
```

[image: window credential]

Comment: Storing a credential in an AHK script is not very secure; malware or attackers look for this sort of thing. See the answer below for a better option.

Answer (score 7):

I use the KeePass AutoType feature to log in to various RDP sessions in the network.

On the Auto-Type tab I add a custom sequence for a specific window.

[image: KeePass Auto-Type custom sequence]

To add the entry I use the default sequence but add {DOWN} to the beginning of it. This means that it doesn't matter what username is currently displayed in the security details as the {DOWN} sequence forces it to use the "Use another account" option.

To set up the custom entry you need to have the Windows security dialog open and waiting for input then go into the KeePass Auto-Type tab and press Add then fill in the box as shown:

[image]

Works for me!

Comment: I use KeePass to log into the hundreds of Windows servers that we maintain.  It should be noted that KeePass cannot log into Windows XP/Server 2003 machines.

Comment: So it can't. Hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Is that a version of keepass that isn't free?  my keypass autotypes(in general anyway) though doesn't have those tabs.  I haven't tested it on the credentials though I guess if I did it wouldn't work and would have the same issue as the op.  Are you using Classic edition or Professional edition, and if the latter, then is it still free?

Comment: It's v2.20.1 the latest "professional" version - and yes, it is most definitely free.